# Solr XConnect Search Web Deploy package URL

Tags: sitecore-client, solr, xconnect, arm-template

I am trying to install Sitecore 9.2.0 XP with SOLR in ARM template. For that I need to put the web deploy package of "Solr XConnect Search Web Deploy package URL" in the place of "xcSearchMsDeployPackageUrl".

Can anyone please share the URL of the WDP. Can't find in https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads or anywhere in the internet.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package needs to be uploaded by you to Azure Storage.

*Solr XConnect Search Web Deploy* package can be downloaded from [Sitecore Developer Portal](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/92/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_92_Initial_Release.aspx), in *Download options for Azure AppService* section.
The name of the package:

`Sitecore 9.2.0 rev. 002893 (Cloud)_xp1collectionsearchsolr.scwdp.zip`.

After that, a recommended approach is to upload the package to your **Azure Storage**.
The URL of the uploaded file can be specified for **"xcSearchMsDeployPackageUrl"** parameter.
For more details you can refer to [Pete Navarra's blog post](https://sitecorehacker.com/2018/01/18/sitecore-9-0-1-on-azure-paas-deployment-guide/) or [this blog post](http://www.navavayas.com/blog/deploy-sitecore-911-xp-scaled-to-azure/).
Example:

```
"xcSearchMsDeployPackageUrl": {
      "value": "#AzureStorageURL#/sitecore-9.2.0-xDBScaled-packages/Sitecore 9.2.0 rev. 002893 (Cloud)_xp1collectionsearchsolr.scwdp.zip"
    },
```